# control custom list component with keyboard using react

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that shows a List with Items inside (names for this example), every name is wrapped under `Item` component which is under `List` component.

What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to "navigate" in the list's items with the keyboard arrows and enter press to act like a mouse click - in the `Input` component (on the current item that you achieved to get on with the arrow keys),

The issue is that I'm not sure how to tackle it, I tried a few ways but every each one of them got into a dead end.

I'm adding an example list in codepen that simulate my original code - that includes also all the modules I'm working with.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rKGdMJ?editors=0011

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one of the approaches could be adding a state with property `itemPosition`. And saving `<List>` component to a `ref`. Then you increase or decrease `itemPosition` using arrows and select an item through the `ref` with something like `childNodes[itemPosition]`. And you handle enter press the similar way then just call `.click()` on the item.

Comment: I tried this approach but for some reason the `childNodes` of the list doesn't get colored of focused,
here is what I tried
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rKGdMJ?editors=0011

Comment: `focus()` won't work here. You need to add hover styles based on props. If your element position in the array is equal to a pointer you apply them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to throw out a big-picture suggestion rather than a particular solution and see if it is helpful.

Handling keypresses in a helpful and consistent manner is a larger problem and a good time to turn to contributed code. It will almost always result in a better outcome than rolling your own system.

For me, I have had good success using the [react-keydown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-keydown) library. I will say, it comes with a little extra setup given that you need to configure webpack to use javascript decorators (let me know if you are interested and want help with that).

Below is a code example that uses the library to control tabbing on a page:

```
class EditContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
    }

  @keydown(
    'ctrl+1', 'meta+1',
    'ctrl+2', 'meta+2',
    'ctrl+3', 'meta+3',
    'ctrl+4', 'meta+4',
    'ctrl+5', 'meta+5',
    'ctrl+6', 'meta+6',
    'ctrl+7', 'meta+7',
    'ctrl+8', 'meta+8',
    'ctrl+9', 'meta+9',
    'ctrl+s', 'meta+s',
    )
  submit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const {panels, changeActivePanel, saveRecord} = this.props;

    if (event.key === "s") {
      saveRecord();
      return;
    }

    const number_key = parseInt(event.key);
    if (!isNaN(number_key) && (number_key <= panels.length)) {
      changeActivePanel(panels[number_key - 1]);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="edit-container">
        <Col sm={10} md={10} lg={10}>
        <EditLeftColumn/>
        </Col>
          <Col sm={2} md={2} lg={2}>
        <EditRightColumn />
          </Col>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And here for reference is my babel.js that lets this work:

```
  "plugins": [
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "syntax-async-functions"
  ],
  "presets": ["env", "react"],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-decorators-legacy"
      ],
      "presets": ["env", "react"]
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, this makes it really easy to bind individual keys to events and it does not require you to have a specific input field in focus.  I think it would be the easiest way to get where you want to go. Comment back if you need more details on implementation. The transform-decorators-legacy is the part you should be interested in to get this library working.

Hope that helps, and good luck!